# Sending a Json File in express

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'm trying to set route in my application to download a .json file when it is opened, however I can't quite figure out how res.sendFile works.  When I send my file, for some reason the client receives a completely blank file with the correct name.

Here's my code:

```
fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../public/send/file.json'), JSON.stringify(resultDict));

res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=file.json');

var options = {
    root: __dirname + '/../../public/send/',
    dotfiles: 'deny',
    headers: {
        'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
        'x-sent': true
    }
};

res.sendFile('file.json', options, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.status(err.status).end();
    }
    else{
        console.log('Sent: ' + "file.json");
    }
});
```

Why is the sent file completely empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `fs.writeFile` function, but not waiting for the callback (which will indicate error, or success) See: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback.

Because of this, by the time the send file code runs, the file has not been written, and so blank contents are sent.

To fix this put everything from `res.setHeader` to the end in a function and add it as the last argument to `fs.writeFile`.